# FAR 121.577 and first class drinks

Tags: faa-regulations

Some airlines offer [drinks for first class before departing](https://eyeoftheflyer.com/2022/05/20/delta-pre-departure-beverages-return/). Would this violate 121.577(a)?

To clarify, (b) discusses tray tables but assume for this question the tray table is up.

According to FAR:

> § 121.577 Stowage of food, beverage, and passenger service equipment during airplane movement on the surface, takeoff, and landing.

> (a) No certificate holder may move an airplane on the surface, take off, or land when any food, beverage, or tableware furnished by the certificate holder is located at any passenger seat.

Comment: My guess is (due to the exclusiveness of "first class") that the ones to complain (apart from the crew) would be the first class passengers themselves. Obviously unlikely.

Answer (score 9):

Offering drinks while at the gate is not a violation, but presumably they would need to suspend service and collect any remaining beverages before pushback to be in compliance.

Answer (score 3):

Typically first class passengers will be the first to board the aircraft. The entire boarding process can take 20 to 30 minutes until the plane is ready to go. Airlines don’t usually have large glasses so if it takes 30 minutes to drink a few ounces of orange juice and there’s something wrong with you.

Comment: What prompted the question was a couple I had dinner with was gushing about 1st class champagne during takeoff. I expected the answers to point out a loophole but apparently some flight staff is more lenient with the rules!

Comment: Not much can be concluded from one data point, especially an anecdotal story by a couple claiming they were served champagne during takeoff. Note that flight attendants are seated and strapped in during the takeoff roll so we already know that this did not literally happen. As for what truth they were possibly stretching a bit that's hard to say. Not everyone who flies is paying that much attention to what the airplane is doing at every moment.

Comment: It has been my experience that the FAs often collect first class beverages, but not always. I've noticed that if a passenger is in the middle of their beverage and don't look like they're going to spill it, the FA might look the other way and let them keep sipping through takeoff. To @StevePemberton's point, though, this is anecdata.